# Module 'emnist' has no attribute 'train_images'

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have tried training and testing the CNN using keras on mnist dataset using same given code. Now I want to try the same code on emnist dataset but it gives the following error:

I am trying the following code

!pip install emnist

```
import numpy as np
import emnist
from tensorflow import keras

train_images = emnist.train_images()
train_labels = emnist.train_labels()

print(train_images.shape) 
print(train_labels.shape)
```

Here is the output:

```
Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-812445794c0d> in <module>
      5 # The first time you run this might be a bit slow, since the
      6 # mnist package has to download and cache the data.
----> 7 train_images = emnist.train_images()
      8 train_labels = emnist.train_labels()
      9 

AttributeError: module 'emnist' has no attribute 'train_images'
```

Please help

Comment: Are you using the same TensorFlow version that is mentioned in the article that you are following/?

Comment: I cannot find the tensorflow version specified in the artile. i am updating it to latest. let's see if it works or not

Comment: Could you link the emnist package in the question? And/or the article?

Comment: I'm simply installing emnist as 
pip install emnist
this query runs good. but the error is after this line as shown above
it is actually an assignment... not article

Answer (score 0):

If you check the website of the emnist package https://pypi.org/project/emnist/

You can see the correct usage is (e.g. using digits dataset):

```
from emnist import extract_training_samples
from emnist import extract_test_samples

images, labels = extract_training_samples('digits')
images, labels = extract_test_samples('digits')
```

There is no train_images method

Answer (score 0):

You can check the emnist python package here to observe how to properly import the functions: https://pypi.org/project/emnist/

You can check which datasets they have by importing the following function:

```
from emnist import list_datasets
list_datasets()
```

Taking the byclass dataset, let's extract the samples:

```
from emnist import extract_training_samples, extract_test_samples
x_train, y_train = extract_training_samples('byclass')
x_test, y_test = extract_test_samples('byclass')
```